# Deploy application on IIS windows server 2008

Tags: web-services, iis, windows-server-2008

I have created a webservice and I want to deploy it on my local machine. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition. Till now I have done following things:

1. Copied compiled file to the folder in WWWROOT folder [MyApp]
   [image: My Application]
2. Shared the folder to all available role in the computer
   [image: Sharing Folder]
3. I have checked in the IIS and I can see the folder here
   [image: IIS]
4. But when I tried to browse it from IIS I am getting this error:
   [image: Broswer]

Please help me.

Comment: Please advice me so that I can post relevant images which would help you all to provide me the solution.

Comment: Was this a webservice (restfull api) or a web-application(webapp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your error screen you will see it say to enable directory browsing in your IIS :)

I think this should do the trick.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you forgot to write Service asmx :)

```
http://localhost/MyApp/Service1.asmx
```

this should work